# How can I get rid of the thin white outline on the upper half of this circle?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get rid of the thin white outline on the upper half of this circle. Any ideas on how to fix it?
    [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NewsletterPolls/v9bLfkpx/)

```css
body {
        background-color: black;
        padding:50px;
    }
    .square {
        background-color: white;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
    .halfSquare {
  background-color: #462a04;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  }
    .circle {
     background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
    .halfCircle {
  background-color: #462a04;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="square"><div class="halfSquare"></div></div>
  <div class="circle"><div class="halfCircle"></div></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Imo you can't if you build it that way. The white pixels should be the point, where the "brown pixel" would be at least a bit (less than a pixel) out of the box of it's container. Therefore it would be overflow and overflow is hidden. So the browser shows the container instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing this because the containing div `.circle` has a white background, which is leaking through. You can fix this by removing the background on the containing div and adding a second div for the white semi circle:

```
<div class="square"><div class="halfSquare"></div></div>
<div class="circle">
     <div class="halfCircle"></div>
     <div class="halfCircle2">
</div></div>

.circle {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.halfCircle {
    background-color: #462a04;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.halfCircle2 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9bLfkpx/1/

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks garryp this works for me. Any idea why it happens on a circle but not a square?

Comment: @NewsletterPoll It doesn't happen on a square because the pixels of container and contained coincide between each other, but there is no such accurate coincidence when is a curved segment, so it gets noticeable for the naked eye.

Comment: There is no anti-aliasing because of the rotation of the square. However if you rotate the square so its sides are at diagonals to the screen you will see a similar problem https://jsfiddle.net/v9bLfkpx/5/

Answer (score 1):

The container has to be transparent. The white border is due to the fact that the container has a white background. Do it this way:

```
<div class="square"><div class="halfSquare"></div></div>
<div class="circle">
   <div class="halfCircle2"></div>
   <div class="halfCircle1"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
        .circle {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .halfCircle2 {
            background-color: #462a04;
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .halfCircle1 {
            background-color: white;
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
        }
```

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9bLfkpx/3/